# Yosemite won't accept administrator password

Tags: macos, password

I've just bought an iMac, reinstalled Yosemite, put in my details but, coming back after a short pause, found it had gone to sleep and wouldn't accept my password to wake up. I'm sure I put in the right one. I've seen advice that re-booting to Recovery might offer a way of recapturing my password, or changing it to a new one, and tried it again and again. But whether I restart holding down Command+R, or holding down the Option key and then choosing to boot from Recovery, I just can't find any options to click that would lead me to either my password or any way to put in a new one.

I'd be grateful for help.

Comment: bring it back to apple store so they can fix it.

Comment: Is the keyboard localized? For some reason it changes in my login screen sometimes and some characters like an underscore or also z and y are on a different key. look in the upper right corner for the current setting and change it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

- Once you are in the Recovery Mode, click in the menu on Utilities, then Terminal.
- Type resetpassword then enter.
- Follow the instructions on screen

Warning: Your keychain can only be unlocked with the old password.